# UI-efficient filtering of WPF TreeView

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, filtering

I need to make a searchable TreeView. If any item matches the search text, then all of its parents automatically match and are expanded. Anything that doesn't match loses its visibility.

Here is my (sample) interface and filtering code:

```
interface ITreeItem : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    IList<ITreeItem> Children { get; }
    string Header { get; }
    bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
    bool IsVisible { get; set; }
}

void Filter(ITreeItem item, string text) {
    foreach (var subItem in item.Children) {
        Filter(subItem, text);
    }
    if (item.Header.IndexOf(text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        item.IsVisible = true;
    else {
        foreach (var subItem in item.Children) {
            if (subItem.IsMatch) {
                item.IsVisible = true;
                item.IsExpanded = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        item.IsVisible = false;
        item.IsExpanded = false;
    }
}
```

This question isn't about the algorithm; it works fine and isn't bottlenecking anything as far as I can tell. My problem is the `NotifyPropertyChanged` for `IsExpanded` on all of the nodes. When the tree has a non-trivial number of items (I can get a significant delay with 100 items with 100 subitems each) there's a huge halt as the UI is bombarded with these property changes.

I've considered just rebuilding the list and assigning the TreeView's `ItemsSource` manually whenever the search text changes, but another unrelated feature (adding/renaming items) means this solution would require a lot of extra bookkeeping.

Comment: Well about algorithm, have you tried not a top 2 bottom approach, but the other way? First without raising INotifyPropertyChanged just determine which nodes should be visible, then find their parents that should also be visible, then find parents' parents... and so on. And after you determine all the matching nodes, then set isVisible & isExpanded. Because right now you are mixing logic and UI

Comment: @bamanow Unless I'm misunderstanding your point, all that will accomplish is separation of the UI updates from the filter code, which does nothing to lighten the massive amount of work done in the UI thread. If I put off the `PropertyChanged` events until the end, there are just as many as before.

Comment: Separating UI and actual filtering is just recommended way of doing things. And usually this is enough to solve slow UI updates. Right now your code works like this: 1) Calculate visibility 2) Update UI 3) Wait for UI update, and these three steps are recursive. It's just like inserting 1000 rows into a database each in its own transaction vs opening transaction, inserting rows, committing transaction. And if this doesn't help have you tried hiding your TreeView before filtering and making it visible after all of the filtering finished?

Comment: @bamanow I understand your point, but I'm not sure there's a (good) way to implement the single transaction instead of many. Toggling the visibility doesn't cause an update. I tried clearing the binding and then setting it again, but that's also slow for a big enough collection.

I've tentatively gone with the alternate solution (building a new list of copied items and settings the tree's item source to that) and it's significantly faster.

Comment: If you can set tree's itemssource with a new list, why can't you assign null to it on search text change, do filtering, and reassign filtered result to it?

Comment: @bamanow Hmm, that seems to get good performance when the tree is virtualized. I had thought of it, but I assumed it would suffer the same pitfalls. Thank you!